# What could be the reason that gdb running my program and just bash running my program show different outputs?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, gdb, valgrind

When I debug my c++ program with gdb in linux? I compile with -g and in fact, I see a lot of information in the debugger but it keeps telling me that my program exits normally and doesn't show any errors.
When I just run my program though, it doesn't finish and shows that not everything is alright (one assertion in malloc.c failed).

I also had the case, that gdb and just running the program showed different error messages. errors are alwazys related to wrong pointers, memory accesses.

Same actually goes for valgrind. Is there the possibility that it is not possible to use valgrind? In particular if there are different processes and a shared library included?

Running it with valgrind by: valgrind --trace-children=yes prog1 gives me no errors (which I cannot be true), if I enable the suppressed errors by: valgrind -v --trace-children=yes prog1, I get warnings about redirection conflicts (don't seem like errors either).

Answer (score 6):

The problem with buggy programs is that their behavior is undefined. They work sometimes, and crash at other times unpredictably.

Both Valgrind and GDB affect the program timing, and may hide race conditions (which could happen for both multithreaded and multiprocess programs).

In addition, GDB disables address-space randomization, making addresses in the program repeatable from run to run. That's usually what you want while debugging, but your crash may only manifest itself for particular random layout of shared libraries, and that layout may never happen under GDB.

Your best bet is to enable generation of core dumps (`ulimit -c unlimited`), run the program outside GDB and have it abort (failing `assert` calls `abort`). Once you have a core, debug it with GDB:  `gdb /path/to/your/executable core`.

For the problems you've described, Valgrind is usually a better tool. If multiple processes are involved, you'll want to run valgrind with `--trace-children=yes` flag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to get the core dumb but I get the message that a.elf doesn't exist. Any other possibilities where the core dumb is saved? Sorry for this, but it's my first time going all of this (gdb, valgrind, core dumb,..)

Comment: The core dump is usually called 'core', but some systems call it 'core.<pid>'. The 'a.elf' was just an example, substitute the name of your crashing executable there. Edited answer to (hopefully) make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a multithreading problem and gdb slows it down enough that your threads don't conflict.  Also maybe the program is being run optimized?  Does valgrind say everything is ok?

Comment: No, program is not being run optimized. What does this mean?

Comment: If compile the program with -g -02 or anything besides -g 00 you are running optimized which will cause gdb to start acting weird.

Comment: compiling it with g++ -g 02 does unfortunately does not change the fact that gdb says the program exits normally.

Answer (score 0):

I would enable all warnings in the compilation with `-Wall`, so that gcc will warn you about uninitialized variables, and then run it inside valgrind. One of them should tell you the problem.

Comment: The first thing to do is to check the size that you are passing into malloc. And once you switch on -Wall, then you kind of reduced the chances that you passed on (uninitialized) huge value in malloc.